# Want to be able to get all of the possible combinations of ABCD for a javascript

Tags: javascript

Question is I have a javascript that looks at my text field class 'setup' this field can contain any of the following letters A,B,C,D in any order or combination. I want to be able to set the value of each combination is their an easy way of doing it rather than hard coding all 340 combinations... please any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.scrap').click(function() {
    var weld_scrap = $('.weld').val();
    var dim_scrap = $('.dim').val();
    var visual_scrap = $('.visual').val();
    var adjust_scrap = $('.adjust').val();
    var setup = $('.setup').val();
    var A = '10';
    var B = '10';
    var C = '10';
    var D = '10';
var AA = '20';
var AB = '20';
var AC = '20';
var AD = '20';
var BA = '20';
var BB = '20';
var BC = '20';
var BD = '20';
var CA = '20';
var CB = '20';
var CC = '20';
var CD = '20';
var DA = '20';
var DB = '20';
var DC = '20';
var DD = '20';
var AAA = '30';
var AAB = '30';
var AAC = '30';
var AAD = '30';
var ABA = '30';
var ABB = '30';
var ABC = '30';
var ABD = '30';
var ACA = '30';
var ACB = '30';
var ACD = '30';
var ADA = '30';
var ADB = '30';
var ADC = '30';
var ADD = '30';
var BAA = '30';
var BAB = '30';
var BAC = '30';
var BAD = '30';
var BBA = '30';
var BBB = '30';
var BBC = '30';
var BBD = '30';
var BCA = '30';
var BCB = '30';
var BCC = '30';
var BCD = '30';
var BDA = '30';
var BDB = '30';
var BDC = '30';
var BDD = '30';
var CAA = '30';
var CAB = '30';
var CAC = '30';
var CAD = '30';
var CBA = '30';
var CBB = '30';
var CBC = '30';
var CBD = '30';
var CCA = '30';
var CCB = '30';
var CCC = '30';
var CCD = '30';
var CDA = '30';
var CDB = '30';
var CDC = '30';
var CDD = '30';
var DAA = '30';
var DAB = '30';
var DAC = '30';
var DAD = '30';
var DBA = '30';
var DBB = '30';
var DBC = '30';
var DBD = '30';
var DCA = '30';
var DCB = '30';
var DCC = '30';
var DCD = '30';
var DDA = '30';
var DDB = '30';
var DDC = '30';
var DDD = '30';
    if (setup == 'A') {
      setup = A;
    }else if (setup == 'B') {
      setup = B;
    }else if (setup == 'C') {
      setup = C; 
    }else if (setup == 'D') {
      setup = D; 
    }else if (setup == 'AA') {

    }
    var sum = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap) + parseInt(setup);  
   console.log(sum);
    $('.scrap').val(sum);
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are those "scraps"? What do you want to do with them? I'm 100% sure there is a way to compute what you want without evaluating all combinations.

Comment: scarps would be the value of the possible combinations of ABCD so for example AB would equal 20 so the scrap amount is 20 @Bergi

Comment: What are the possible values of the inputs, what would `weld_scrap,dim_scrap, visual_scrap, adjust_scrap` contain? And more imporantly, what can `$('.setup').val()` be?

Comment: It looks very much like you want `setup = setup.length*10` (for any one- to four-digit strings `setup`)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```js
var pArr = [],
  usedChars = [];

function permute(input) {
  var index, char;
  for (index = 0; index < input.length; index++) {
    char = input.splice(index, 1)[0];
    usedChars.push(char);
    if (input.length == 0) {
      pArr.push(usedChars.slice());
    }
    permute(input); //Recursive
    input.splice(index, 0, char);
    usedChars.pop();
  }
  return pArr
};


document.write(JSON.stringify(permute(["A", "B", "C", "D"])));
```

Comment: The OP seems to want all *combinations* of 1,2 or 3 characters from the set {A, B, C, D}, not all permutations.

Comment: @Asad: He also wants permutations on top of that, e.g. he has both `ABD` and `DAB` in his list

Comment: @Bergi You're right, didn't look at the assignments carefully enough. Still, this answer needs to be modified to also produce permutations of 1...n elements, where n is the size of the input.